# How to push item to Obj Array by his index

Tags: javascript

I need to push my item into Obj Array and right now I'm getting last record multiple times.

codepen: https://codepen.io/dolezalp/pen/YzXjEoo

```js
const hitpoints = ["one", "two", "three"];
let remapImages = new Array();
const item = new Object();

hitpoints.forEach(function(i, index) {
  item.img = document.getElementById(i);
  item.hit = document.getElementById(i).offsetTop - window.innerHeight;
  console.log(item);
  remapImages.push(item);
});

console.log(remapImages);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="one">1</li>
  <li id="two">2</li>
  <li id="three">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Declare `item` inside the forEach callback function.

Comment: Currently your code creates a single object which gets updated and pushed in every iteration. `remapImages.push(item);` does not create a copy of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create more than just one object, otherwise you are pushing the same object reference multiple times:

```
const hitpoints = ["one", "two", "three"];
let remapImages = new Array();

hitpoints.forEach(function(i, index) {
  const item = new Object();
  item.img = document.getElementById(i);
  item.hit = document.getElementById(i).offsetTop - window.innerHeight;
  console.log(item);
  remapImages.push(item);
});

console.log(remapImages);
```

And since its a reference it gets updated in the foreach loop and that's why you see multiple times the latest values of that object.